# How to start a npm-package?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, npm-install, minecraft, npm-start

I want to program a Minecraft Bedrock Addon with JavaScript, just installed these packages "npm install -g yo" and "npm install -g generator-minecraft-addon". This all worked great. Now I want to continue with the settings of the mod, for this I have entered "yo minecraft-addon" in the terminal and this error message appears:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUezi.png

This is the error message.
I hope you can read it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sadly the error is in German (I think). Please may you put the error in the question as text so we might be able to use a translator?

Comment: Without translating it looks like the terminal doesn't think yo is installed. Maybe try restarting the terminal?

Comment: Your question is in English, please translate the error to English as well.

Answer (score 0):

Create a package.
json file, on the command line, in the root directory of your Node. js module, run npm init : For scoped modules, run npm init --scope=@scope-name. For unscoped modules, run npm init.